# Where are all those emails stored in postfix, location of storage of emails so that I could backup?

Tags: backup, email, postfix, storage

I am a newbie in linux. Recently, I have installed postfix MTA in xubuntu. I just want to know where are all the emails stored in my postfix server.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure), mail is stored in `/var/mail/`.